# Find if zip folder is present in c#

Tags: c#, file

Need quick help. Lets assume there is a zip folder by name `test(d:\test.zip)`.  I need to check if zipped folder(i.e `test`) is present under `d`-directory or what ever, doesn't matter here' and move the `test.zip` to another directory.

I tried using  `Directory.GetDirectories()` method, but it will only work for folders.

Comment: Use `File.Exists`. A "zip folder" as you put it is just a ui trick, it's always a file.

Comment: Didn't think of using File.Exists as i didn't expect zip file to be treated it like a file. Thnx for the soln. Really helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method `File.Exists(path)` to check if a file exists and the method `File.Move(source, destination)` to move a file.

E.g:

```
var zipFile = "d:\\test.zip";
var destination = "d:\\some\\other\\directory";

if (File.Exists(zipFile))
{
    File.Move(
        zipFile,
        Path.Combine(destination, Path.GetFileName(zipFile)));
}
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thnx! Got to know more abt File.Exists!

Comment: @karthikmr You should accept this answer if you feel it resolves your question.